# Why 'zip argument must support iteration' Error occurs in this code?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm building handwritten text recognition nn, and I've tried to excute this code but i got 'zip argument #2 must support iteration' and i can't understand why this error occurs
please help

```
char_arr = [c for c in r"""i(jQXr).gA&t#enw75:0l6*2KVOz/hL-?UIP'bv,McTJ9pdY4xfy3+"N1ZHDSqGWCFE!skRoB;8uam"""]
num_dic = {n: i for i, n in enumerate(char_arr)}

global_step = tf.Variable(0,trainable=False)

Y = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.int32)

data_label = 'apple'

indices = [[i] for i in range(0,len(data_label))]
values = [char_arr.index(c) for c in list(data_label)]
shape = [len(data_label)]
label = tf.SparseTensorValue(indices, values, shape)

label = tf.convert_to_tensor_or_sparse_tensor(label)


sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X : model, Y : label, keep_prob : 0.6})

print('Step :',global_step,', label :',data_label)
```

and I got these errors :

```
  File "<ipython-input-6-44645c5acb58>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/samsung/Desktop/손글씨/HC+nn_v2.py', wdir='C:/Users/samsung/Desktop/손글씨')

  File "C:\Users\samsung\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\samsung\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/samsung/Desktop/손글씨/HC+nn_v2.py", line 136, in <module>
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X : base, Y : label, keep_prob : 0.6})

  File "C:\Users\samsung\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)

  File "C:\Users\samsung\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1072, in _run
    for subfeed, subfeed_val in _feed_fn(feed, feed_val):

  File "C:\Users\samsung\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1052, in _feed_fn
    return feed_fn(feed, feed_val)

  File "C:\Users\samsung\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 111, in <lambda>
    [feed.indices, feed.values, feed.dense_shape], feed_val)),

TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration
```

Comment: The text `zip` does not appear in the code you've posted. Can you show us the entire error with full stack trace?

Comment: i think the cause of error is SparseTensor but i don't know exactly how can i fix it

Comment: Remove the line `label = tf.convert_to_tensor_or_sparse_tensor(label)`, that is converting your [`tf.SparseTensorValue`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensorValue) into a [`tf.SparseTensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/SparseTensor), but the [`tf.sparse_placeholder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/placeholder) expects a [`tf.SparseTensorValue`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensorValue).

Comment: thanks but another error occurs 